# I am doing an excercise in my book and this code shows errors

Tags: java

```
public class Object {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount account;
        account = getAccount();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The account balance of $"
                + account.getBalance());
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static BankAccount getAccount() {
        String input;
        double balance;

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter");

        balance = Double.parseDouble(input);
        return new BankAccount(balance);
    }
}
```

The error is that it cannot find the "BankAccount" symbol. I'm trying to return an object and display. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Don't make a class named `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

You've not actually declared a `BankAccount` class. You have a static method that returns a `BankAccount`, but it was never declared anywhere.

Comment: How can I declare a class within the same file? The book does not show this as a seperate class.

Answer (score 1):

As @Slaks says, the name `Object` is not a good idea since Java already has a class named `Object`. Try to find a more descriptive name for your class.

As for the error, the compiler doesn't know what the BankAccount class is. You need to provide this class somehow. If you haven't written the BankAccount class yet, you need to do so. If you have already written it, then the compiler isn't finding it. The exact method to solve this depends on how you are compiling your code. Are you using an IDE or a command-line compiler?

Comment: I'm using Netbeans. However, the book I"m learning from does not show this excercies as there being a Bank Account class. Maybe it was authors error.

Comment: Is part of the exercise to create the BankAccount class? Or is there a BankAccount class which is used throughout the book or in this particular chapter?

Comment: no. but maybe it's hidden somewhere. I get where you're coming from. However, i do remember that students n class were saying that this book had a few errors. maybe this was one of them.

Answer (score 0):

As the error **clearly** states, the compiler doesn't know about a `BankAccount` class.